# No Route matches "say/hello" when route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a very simple Hello, world program in RoR, but when I go to view the url http://localhost:3000/say/hello I'm getting the error message No route matches: "say/hello"

I started with: rails generate controller Say hello goodbye
which lists route get "say/hello"

Also: I'm having this problem which is probably related. When I go to write some basic html in one of the files that is clearly listed as existing I get this:

I write this:

```
~/work/demo$ /app/views/say/hello.html.erb
```

Get this error message in return:

```
bash: /app/views/say/hello.html.erb: No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? I'm getting these instructions straight from Agile Development with Rails and it's so simple.

Comment: type "rake routes". This will show you a list of valid routes for your application. I am willing to bet that your route is not listed. Your Say controller does have a hello action, but you haven't added the route to your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

With the details you've given I'm not sure why your route can't be found.

However, I believe the reason you're experiencing the no such file or directory error is because you're typing /app/views/say/hello.html.erb. Try removing the leading slash, so that it reads app/views/say/hello.html.erb. Bash appears to be parsing the former path as an absolute path, instead of a path relative to your current working directory.

Comment: okay. when i use /app/views/say/hello.html.erb  it says permission denied. When i use sudo it says command app/views/say/hello.html.erb not found

Answer (score 0):

What is this command?

```
~/work/demo$ /app/views/say/hello.html.erb
```

you should be using your web browser: `http://localhost:3000/say/hello`